# MySQL behaves strange in sort and select order by limit when rows have identical column vlaue

Tags: mysql, sorting, select, limit

I have a table with 6 rows of data with id=11,12,13,14,15,18 after I inserted row id=18 by cloning id=12. I select data from the table by a column (c1) and it happens that those 6 rows all have the same column value. I tried to use select limit to loop through all rows where c1=2;

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE c1=2 LIMIT 0,2 ;
```

-> I got 15,14

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE c1=2 LIMIT 2,2 ;
```

-> I got 13,11

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE c1=2 LIMIT 4,2 ;
```

-> I got 15, 18

How comes id=12 is missing and id=15 appears twice?
Did I miss anything? Shall I resort the table or do something after I insert a new row ?

Things happen to be more complicated than just adding ORDER BY. All 6 rows have the same c1 column values. If I used `ORDER BY c1 DESC`, then I got the same undesired result. However those 6 rows have different values on column c2. When I used `ORDER BY c2 DESC`, I can loop through all 6 rows of data correctly. Now comes another question - why mysql does not ORDER and return `SELECT ** ORDER by yy DESC LIMIT 2, 2` correctly when all rows have identical yy column value.

Of course we know ID will be different for all rows, but we don't know where all rows in the table would have different c1 value (which was used in ORDER BY) or not. What shall we do if we do need `ORDER BY C1` ?

Comment: A limit *without* an order by is never going to return anything reproducable. The database is free to return the rows in whatever order it thinks makes sense. If you order by something where you have identical values, the same happens. The order of the rows where the columns have the same value is undefined. If you want a stable sort, add a column that makes the sort "unique".

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name,

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks for your response. It happens very often that select query might get rows which have many rows with identical value such as AGE. In this case it is not safe when use limit to loop through rows in pagination if rows have identical value. Shall I use  'SELECT **** ORDER BY c1, id LIMIT ****' ? In this case, id column will guarantee unique; but will this increase the overhead ?

Comment: See: [MySQL Bug #69732](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69732) for more details.